# Title for a list of disclaimers, prerequisites, FYIs

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, formality

I'm about to start a workshop and I'd like to have a "before we start" slide in which I'll communicate:

- several prerequisites for attendees to better understand the content,
- set several boundaries in regards to content presented and its format,
- and perhaps some general notes as well.

Roughly, something like:

```
1. This workshop assumes you understand concept x;
2. Bringing a laptop is not mandatory;
3. Please interrupt me at anytime if something is not clear;
4. I'll answer any question - I hope we don't deviate too much from the main topic :)
5. I won't give any homework, although I strongly recommend practicing at home
etc.
```

Is there a word/simple phrase that would accurately describe such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Guidelines," "Ground Rules," or "Expectations" all come to mind as words or phrases you could use for such a list.

As an aside, I wouldn't use a semicolon at the end of the members of a bulleted list. Use a full stop, or simply forgo closing punctuation altogether.